# Should tags [marker] and [markers] be synonyms?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

We currently have two tags that, in my opinion should be synonyms.

I think [marker](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marker) and [markers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/markers) are identical.  Does anyone object to them being merged?  Or is there another definition that I'm not aware of?

I suggest making [markers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/markers) the master tag as it is tagged on more questions and has a more complete definition. Further, it seems our tendency is to make the plural the master and the singular the synonym.  For example [join](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/join) is  a synonym of [joins](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/joins) and [domain](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/domain) is a synonym of [domains](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/domains).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - I think that you should merge tag [marker](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marker) into [markers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/markers) (leaving [marker](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marker) as a synonym of it) for all of the reasons that you have provided in your question.

Comment: Thanks PolyGeo.  That's now done.